# simple lookup takes several minutes despite using an index

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I have a decently sized graph (~600 million nodes, 3.5 billion edges) that I imported into neo4j. The graph is also quite dense (median edge count around 10); though I'm not sure if that affects performance.

For one type of node `(:Authors)` - there are roughly 200 million nodes of this type -  I would like to run a query for a specific name, which is stored in the property `normalizedName`. Here is the (very simple) query:

```
MATCH (a:AUTHOR)
WHERE a.normalizedName = "jonathan smith"
RETURN a
```

As one might expect, this query takes a LONG (several minutes) time to execute. Although I have no explicit guarantee of uniqueness on this property, I still tried to create an index on it, and I got no complaints from neo4j. Afterwards, I would have expected that above query would execute in ms, due to the O(1) complexity for lookups in an index. Unfortunately, the query still takes several minutes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give the explain of the query ? Did you wait the population of the index ? You can check the status of the indexes by typing `:schema` in the browser. If the status is `online` it's ok.

Comment: @logisima You are correct, the index still says that it is populating. I guess I will wait until it finished (may take a while) and then report back if that fixes the issue.

Comment: and check the `debug.log` to see if everything is going well :)

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you have set the index as

```
CREATE INDEX ON :AUTHOR(normalizedName)
```

Be aware that you will need to set an index on each property you wish to use an index look-up on. This is also filtered by node label, i.e. if you're using multiple labels on a node and need an index look up, you would need to set one per label, e.g. if you had :Person:Author, you'd also need to set:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(normalizedName)
```