# Is it possible to see the progress of an index in neo4j?

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58688681/simple-lookup-takes-several-minutes-despite-using-an-index?noredirect=1#comment103695356_58688681) a while ago about a query being slow. What appears to be the answer is that the index is still populating, as it is quite large (around 200M entries), and that I should try again once that has finished, i.e., check via `:schema` if the index is up / in the `DONE` state rather than `POPULATING`.

My current problem is that I've had it running for a few days now, and it is still populating. I checked the `debug.log` (and any other log I found) for clues, but nothing seems to indicate failure of the process.

My main question is: Is there any way to visualize the current progress of an index being built? Also, can I speed things up by restarting the server with more resources?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the progress by calling `db.indexes()`.

```
CALL db.indexes()
YIELD description, progress, state
WHERE description CONTAINS ':Label'
RETURN description, progress, state
```

I am sure more memory/cpu always helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Neo4j 5.x it you need to use `SHOW INDEXES` command.

```
SHOW INDEXES YIELD name, state, populationPercent
```